# Errors installing Zoom conferencing

Tags: software-installation, zoom-meeting

I downloaded zoom from https://zoom.us/download?os=linux
Wrote the following installation code. Installation started, bud then there is this "Error were encountered while processing: zoom

Does not tell me much...

```
~$ sudo dpkg -i Downloads/zoom_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package zoom.
(Reading database ... 212204 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack Downloads/zoom_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zoom (2.0.115900.1201) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zoom:
 zoom depends on libxcb-xtest0; however:
  Package libxcb-xtest0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package zoom (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zoom
~$
```

Comment: It wants you to install `libxcb-xtest0`, so run `sudo apt-get install libxcb-xtest0`, then run the `dpkg -i` thing again.

Comment: Glad it helped. I've added an answer, and you are welcome to accept it.

Comment: Thank you  - that solved the problem.  I assumed zoom_amd64.deb contained everything required. I obviously have to learn to read the log better. Last time I installed Zoom I did not have to install libxcb-xtest0 separately.

Comment: $ sudo apt install libxcb-xtest0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libxcb-xtest0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libxcb-xtest0' has no installation candidate

Comment: this is STILL an issue with zoom install 3 years later ... below solutions work yet Zoom should step up and FIX their install .deb process ...  thankfully we have askubuntu

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The software in question (Zoom) requires `libxcb-xtest0`. The package is in the repositories, and can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xtest0
```

Note, this should be done prior to the installation of zoom.

Comment: It fixed it for me even after Zoom installation :)

Comment: $ sudo apt install libxcb-xtest0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libxcb-xtest0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libxcb-xtest0' has no installation candidate

Comment: @Bus42 The package `libxcb-xtest0` is still in the repositories. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&searchon=names&keywords=libxcb-xtest0. I suspect you make have an unsupported release.

Answer (score 26):

Zoom requires `libxcb-xtest0`
You can do this in the terminal, navigate to where you have downloaded the '.deb' file.

```
cd ~/Download/
```

then type in:

```
sudo dpkg -i zoom_amd64.deb
```

after it runs .... type in this:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

everything will be installed. Please do have internet.

Comment: thx u but i get this error:

Comment: dpkg: error processing package zoom (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zoom

Comment: Thanks, it works for me.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I had the similar problem while installing zoom, using following steps

```
wget https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_amd64.deb
```

```
sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
```

It showed errors but it was resolved when I used

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

It installed all the dependencies and fixed the broken installation of zoom

After that you can just type `zoom` on terminal to verify, it will open up zoom login page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's just a broken package now and there is no longer any way to install it on Ubuntu. There are dependencies that don't exist anymore. The package needs to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently when installing the zoom meeting, I had a problem related to some dependencies.
It turns out that previously I had changed my mirrors to one with a higher speed, and by changing to the "original" mirrors the problem was solved.

Steps to solve my problem:

1. I edited the /etc/apt/source.list file for the standard mirrors
2. I ran a `sudo apt update`
3. and finally `sudo apt install -f`