# Can't update or reinstall Zoom in 22.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, dpkg

After a summer away, Zoom would not run without an update. After following the instructions and downloading the .deb package, all attempts to install ended with an error:

> dpkg: error processing archive /home/rich/Downloads/zoom_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  unable to open
> '/opt/zoom/email/static/img/icon_video.e36fddbe.svg.dpkg-new':
> Operation not permitted

The file mentioned in the "unable to open" message is different every time, although the extension is always dpkg-new. I tried removing and purging zoom, apt clean, autoremove, rebooting. Nothing helps.

Any suggestions? For now I have to grit my teeth and boot Windows when I do a Zoom call. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the same issue on another askubuntu post https://askubuntu.com/questions/990580/errors-installing-zoom-conferencing try this

Comment: That's not the same issue, is it?

Comment: AFAIK the `.dpkg-new` files are leftovers from previously failed installs. They are temporary files, which would have been `mv`ed into place at the instant of instalation. They weren't, because the previous install failed. Simply delete them. Start with `sudo find /opt/zoom -type f -name '*.dpkg-new' -ls` to list the files, replace `-ls` with `-delete` to delete them. Read `man find sudo dpkg`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but there is no zoom directory in /opt either before or after the failed install. I watched /opt during an install (also failed) and found that /opt/zoom was created and populated, so the installation at least got that far. But as soon as the error appeared in the installation script, the directory disappeared, so it was impossible to tell what files were there at the moment of failure. I don't see why some random file would cause trouble, especially a different one every time. My system disk is only 53% full, so it's not running out of space.